# Programmatically run only the unit tests that compile?

Tags: eclipse, compilation, junit5

I develop an application to grade student code. Their grade should depend on the number of unit tests (that I provide) that pass (using their code).

I understand that I can launch unit tests programmatically using the JUnit Launcher. That’s great. But, what if some of those tests do not compile (for example, because the student forgot to provide a method accessed by a test)? I still want to run the other unit tests, the ones that compile, to determine the student’s grade.

In other words, I would like to program a behavior similar to Eclipse’s behavior. Eclipse will accept to start a set of unit tests even when some do not compile (simply failing the tests that do not compile).

I guess, but I am not sure, that Eclipse replaces the methods that do not compile, under the hood (making them throw an Error instead), and compiles the resulting code. In which case, JUnit is not involved at all in the process. Is this understanding right? If so, my question is: how can I programmatically compile code as Eclipse does (replacing those methods that do not compile, so that I can afterwards run the unit tests and count how many passed)?

If JUnit launcher itself can be used to compile code (or, perhaps equivalently, can be provided source code instead of compiled code), then is there some documentation about this somewhere? I couldn’t find it in the [JUnit 5 User Guide](https://junit.org/junit5/docs/current/user-guide/).